# How to maintain the state (history) for breadcrumb

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, navigation, breadcrumbs

I'm struggling trying to implement breadcrumb functionality for a directory navigation system.

In my application an user can upload a zip file. Once he do that he can navigate for the content of the zip file (ie navigate for its folders and files). I already implemented that logic. Now I want to add breadcrumbs on top of the page so the user can click on a previous folder and go back to it. I decided to create a pretty Url but I use numbers (Ids) on it to retrieve the upload and folder (or file) from the database. If the user is currently navigation in the upload with `id = 10` and he is in `MainDirectory/folder1` and folder1 has `id = 100` then the Url will be `localhost:1234/upload/10/dir/100/MainDirectory/folder1/`. I have both id the upload and the folder (or file).

When creating the breadcrumb I can retrieve the history from the last part of the Url but I don't have the `id` of those folders. I cannot use the folder name as the key because it is not unique. I thought about putting all ids on the Url but then it will become ugly, something like this: `localhost:1234/upload/10/dir/99/100/MainDirectory/folder1/`. The idea was putting first all ids and then the pretty path.

Session came to mind but I rejected it because the user can navigate in different tabs at the same time, the breadcrumb history depends on the current page. I think that the information to build the breadcrumb needs to be sent on each request.

I cannot think in a better design. Any ideas?

EDIT: I just need to mirror the [github](https://github.com/) navigation system for repositories.

Comment: could you add a list of breadcrumb items or something to your model?

Comment: @aw04 I need to get the info to build the breadcrumb from the request. I'm looking for the best way of storing it and the best way of sending it with the request (that the user make by clicking a link)

Comment: "I cannot use the folder name as the key because it is not unique" - but *in* a particular [Zip file] directory the name *is* unique. The upload ID serves as the discriminator for the start of the directory tree.

Comment: @user2864740 I mean "not unique" for retrieving it from the database. I unzip the upload and store it. If the user clicks on a link to `localhost:1234/upload/10/dir/100/MainDirectory/folder1/` I use `id=10` to get the current upload and `id=100` to get the current folder (**folder1**). But for MainDirectory I don't have the `id` to generate the correct link in breadcrumb.

Comment: So store the path structure in the database as well - then let it serve as the look-up index. The most trivial way us to simply use a materialized path. Otherwise you'll have to encode the "ID" or other "ugly opaque identifier".

Comment: @user2864740 path structure reflects the structure in the original zip file. I unzip the file but keep the structure. Each directory contain a list of directories and a list of files. You can think that I'm navigating on the file system with uploads being system partitions.

Comment: So what *is* the problem with using `/upload/10/dir/MainDirectory/folder1/`? Then there is a KEY formed by (UPLOAD_ID, PATH) such as (10, "dir/MainDirectory/folder1/").

Comment: @user2864740 In breadcrumb the link to MainDirectory should be `/upload/10/dir/xxx/MainDirectory` where `xxx` is the `id` of MainDirectory I don't have this when the user is on `/upload/10/dir/MainDirectory/folder1/`

Comment: The "Main Directory" (for that upload) is the entity known by the KEY (10, "dir/MainDirectory/") or KEY (10, "MainDirectory/"). Why does the id of the directory matter?

Comment: @user2864740 I use the Id to retrieve that folder from DB. This way a can print it content (files and folders). But I think that you are suggesting that I should use a different key on my DB. Am I wrong?

Comment: *Why* are you insistent that an "ID" is required for a lookup? :) A table can have *multiple* KEYs. An auto-increment surrogate PK can be used in *addition* to another key, such as (UPLOAD_ID, PATH).

Comment: @user2864740 I see. thanks for clearing my mind. But what would be the performance penalty for using a key that is a string? I will have a lot of uploads which implies lot of directories on the same directory table in my DB.

Comment: @agarwaen "Inconsequential". The KEY(UPLOAD_ID,PATH) will/should be *indexed* as well and since the left-part (UPLOAD_ID) is always known/specified in queries then the PATH (really, the entire KEY) can participate in [Sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) queries.

Comment: @user2864740 I have to read about SARGABLE queries. Thanks for the hint.